# If statement or else statement in this jquery script?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I tried to alter this script by adding  `$opened = false;` and following up further down. The intention was to enable just one `.textwrap` div to be clicked open at a time so when you click another one the first one fades out and the second in. What I did however only allows one `.textwrap` to be clicked open and I then have to click it closed again before being able to click open the next `.textwrap`. I tried swapping `if ( $opened == false )` to `else ( $opened == false )` and that completely cranked the script. Would appreciate some guidance here. Thanks

#### jQuery:

```
<script>
    $opened = false;

    $('.smallwrap').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).find('.textwrap'),
            pic = $(this).find('.picwrap'),
            clicked = false;

        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(text).stop().fadeIn(200);
        }, function(){
            if ( clicked == false ) {
                $(text).stop().fadeOut(150);
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        });

        $(this).on('click', function(){
            if ( clicked == false ) {
                if ( $opened == false ) {
                    $(text).show();
                    clicked = true;
                    $opened = true;
                }
            } else {
                $(text).stop().fadeOut(150, function(){
                clicked = false;
                $opened = false;
            });
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id="infowrap">
    <div class="mainwrap">
        <div class="smallwrap">
            <div class="picwrap"><a href="#"><img class="pic" alt="pic1" src="img/pic1.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="textwrap"><p>Mustache art party pug whatever mixtape, pork belly sriracha gentrify swag. Try-hard selvage butcher high life, hashtag DIY ennui.</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="smallwrap">
            <div class="picwrap"><a href="#"><img class="pic" alt="pic1" src="img/pic1.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="textwrap"><p>Mustache art party pug whatever mixtape, pork belly sriracha gentrify swag. Try-hard selvage butcher high life, hashtag DIY ennui.</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="smallwrap">
            <div class="picwrap"><a href="#"><img class="pic" alt="pic1" src="img/pic1.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="textwrap"><p>Mustache art party pug whatever mixtape, pork belly sriracha gentrify swag. Try-hard selvage butcher high life, hashtag DIY ennui.</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="smallwrap">
            <div class="picwrap"><a href="#"><img class="pic" alt="pic1" src="img/pic1.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="textwrap"><p>Mustache art party pug whatever mixtape, pork belly sriracha gentrify swag. Try-hard selvage butcher high life, hashtag DIY ennui.</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#infowrap {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.96);
    z-index: 900;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top:10px;left:10px;right:10px;bottom:10px;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.mainwrap {
    width: 540px;
    height: 540px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

.smallwrap {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.picwrap {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.pic {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.textwrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.smallwrap:nth-child(1) .textwrap {
    left: -225px;
    top: 0px;
}

.smallwrap:nth-child(2) .textwrap {
    right: -225px;
    top: 0px;
}

.smallwrap:nth-child(3) .textwrap {
    left: -225px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.smallwrap:nth-child(4) .textwrap {
    right: -225px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML too? Or, even better so, a jsFiddle to show your scenario.

Comment: I added the relevant html and css here since I haven't really tried jsfiddle out yet, hope it is ok.

Comment: The usual way to approach this type of interactivity is to close (fadeOut or hide) all sibling elements unconditionally and to toggle "this" one.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to jquery so a more hands on code example would be super.

Comment: add extra attribute to divs to handle that div is open or not

Comment: If I could combine boz's and UmairP's solutions so I could open and close the divs by clicking any .smallwrap as in boz's and still keep the hover as in UmairP's that would be exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

in html part, make this change;

```
<div class="smallwrap" isopen="false">
```

and your new javascript;

```
    $('.smallwrap').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).find('.textwrap'),
            pic = $(this).find('.picwrap'),
            isopen = $(this).attr('isopen');

        $(this).hover(function () {
            $(text).stop().fadeIn(200);
        }, function () {
            if (isopen == false) {
                $(text).stop().fadeOut(150);
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        });

        $(this).on('click', function () {
            $('.textwrap').stop().fadeOut(150, function () { });
            $(text).show();
            $('.smallwrap').attr('isopen', 'false');
            $(this).attr('isopen','true');
        });
    });
```

Comment: It seems like this solution makes the .textwrap stay open at hover.

Comment: Is it possible to only make it stay open when clicked and then click any of the four .smallwrap to close?

Answer (score 0):

The global variable `$opened` cannot be used in this scenario because it doesn't tell which text is visible. An alternate approach is to mark the clicked text (by assigning it a dummy class)

I have created jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RzU2C/) with a working solution

This is the code that I used.

```
$('.smallwrap').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).find('.textwrap'),
            pic = $(this).find('.picwrap'),
            clicked = false;

        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(text).stop().fadeIn(200);
        }, function(){
            if ( !text.hasClass('isClicked')) {
                $(text).stop().fadeOut(150);
            } 
        });

        $(this).on('click', function(){          
          $('.textwrap','.smallwrap').removeClass('isClicked').stop().fadeOut(150, function(){
            $(text).addClass('isClicked').stop().fadeIn(200);
          });          
        });
    });
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! Just one detail, if I click on div and it opens the linked .textwrap is it possible to click that same div again to make it close? Now you have to click another one in order to get the first one to close, meaning that when you start opening divs you can never close all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The `hover` seems to conflict with the click when it comes to showing the content. Here is an approach without the `hover` part. All I'm doing is adding a class on click and checking if an element with that class exists when I click on another item.

```
$('.smallwrap').click(function(){
    // store $(this) for later use
    $this = $(this);
    // if you've clicked on an open item, close it
    if($this.hasClass('opened')){
        $('.smallwrap').removeClass('opened');
        $('.textwrap').stop().fadeOut(200);
    } else {
        // if an open item exists
        if($('.opened').length != 0){
            // fade out the opened item
            $('.opened').children('.textwrap').fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('.smallwrap').removeClass('opened'); 
                // fade in the item you clicked on
                $this.addClass('opened');
                $this.children('.textwrap').stop().fadeIn(200); 
            });
        } else {
            // fade in the item you clicked on
            $this.addClass('opened');
            $this.children('.textwrap').stop().fadeIn(200); 
        }
    }
});
```

**jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fZkh7/** (I gave your images a red background for debugging)

---

**EDIT**

I managed to get the `hover` working:

```
$('.smallwrap').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.textwrap').stop().fadeIn(200);
}, function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        // hide if it isn't already opened
        $(this).children('.textwrap').stop().fadeOut(150);
    }
});

$('.smallwrap').click(function(){
    // store $(this) for later use
    $this = $(this);
    // if you've clicked on an open item, close it
    if($this.hasClass('opened')){
        $('.smallwrap').removeClass('opened');
        $('.textwrap').stop().fadeOut(200);
    } else {
        // if an open item exists
        if($('.opened').length != 0){
            // fade out the opened item
            $('.opened').children('.textwrap').fadeOut(200, function(){
                $('.smallwrap').removeClass('opened'); 
                // fade in the item you clicked on
                $this.addClass('opened');
                $this.children('.textwrap').stop().fadeIn(200); 
            });
        } else {
            // fade in the item you clicked on
            $this.addClass('opened');
            $this.children('.textwrap').stop().fadeIn(200); 
        }
    }
});
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fZkh7/1/

Comment: As you say this works exactly as I want except for the hover part. Is there no possibility to combine this script with UmairP's? I tried but just got it all to stop working.